# Is it safe for a production server to have make installed?

Tags: security, make, gcc

During the setup of my virtual server instances I require some applications to be built using `make`. Are there any security risks associated with having `make` installed? Or should I clean it up before the instance is deployed?

I also have the `gcc` compiler on the server which I use to build applications before deployment.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, *any* piece of software installed *anywhere* creates a vulnerability.

Comment: And one with non-root shell access to a server could download a "distro independent" compiler package(.tar.gz) that will not need to be installed so...

Comment: Is it me, or is the combination of "is it safe?" and "root access" rather [uncomfortable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathon_Man_%28film%29)?

Comment: If you already have gcc installed, there's practically no way that make could make any potential security problem worse.

Comment: @Shadur What difference does having GCC make? If the user already has access to the machine they can upload any copy of gcc trivially. Anyway, gcc can be useful to unprivileged users and not a security risk as long as no privileged users run it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote server security: handling compiler tools](http://serverfault.com/questions/143364/remote-server-security-handling-compiler-tools)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Some people will argue that the presence of development tools on a production machine will make life easier for an attacker. This however is such a tiny roadbump to an attacker, that any other argument you can find for or against installing the development tools will weigh more.

If an attacker was able to penetrate the system so far, that they could invoke whatever tools are present on the server, then you already have a serious security breach. Without development tools there are many other ways to write binary data to a file and then run a chmod on that file. An attacker wanting to use a custom build executable on the system at this point could just as well build that on their own machine and transfer it to the server.

There are other much more relevant things to look out for. If an installed piece of software contains a security bug, there is a few ways it could be exposed to an attacker:

- The package could contain a suid or sgid executable.
- The package could be starting services on the system.
- The package could install scripts that are invoked automatically under certain circumstances (this includes cron jobs, but scripts could be invoked by other events for example when the state of a network interface changes or when a user logs in).
- The package could install device inodes.

I would not expect development tools to match one of the above, and as such is not a high risk package.

If you have workflows in which you would make use of the development tools, then you first have to decide whether those are reasonable workflows, and if they are, you should install the development tools.

If you find that you don't really need those tools on the server, you should refrain from installing them for multiple reasons:

- Saves disk space, both on the server and on backups.
- Less installed software makes it easier to track what your dependencies are.
- If you don't need the package, there is no point in taking the additional security risk from having it installed, even if that security risk is tiny.

If you decide that for security reasons, you won't allow unprivileged users to put their own executabels on the server, then what you should avoid is not the development tools but rather directories writable to those users on file systems mounted with execute permissions. There may still be a use for development tools even under those circumstances, but it is not very likely.

Comment: I would add to this that a number of production system rely on interpreted code (e.g. PHP, Perl, Python, ...). Banning development tools in this context wouldn't make sense. I'd consider compilers like `gcc` not to present a higher risk than these. As you say, an attacker in a position to use the compilers installed on a system would generally by in a position to do worse things anyway, such as uploading their own (possibly statically linked) executable.

Comment: Relevant: [A tiny version of wget (51 bytes?)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57310/a-tiny-version-of-wget-51-bytes). A real life example of an attacker moving a binary to the server using subsequent `echo` statements into a file. The whole process is automated with a script found in the same link.

Comment: @Adnan, interesting. As far as I can tell, the main security flaw in this DVR example is the fact that the attacker can telnet to it as root with password 123456 in the first place. Having or not having wget or other tools (before the attack) is then barely relevant indeed.

Answer (score 16):

`make` itself is fine. `make` is merely a dependency tracking and automation framework. It is typically used in conjunction with compilers, though, and those preferrably should not be available on a production system, as they're completely un-necessary. The same holds true for all un-needed packages, whether those be shared libraries, interpreters, etc. Software installed on production systems should be strictly controlled, and only those packages that are required by the application should be present.

You should be building your application on a build server, packaging it, and then deploying the binary package to your production systems.

Note: native packaging tools *suck*. Don't even bother trying to grok them. Instead, check out Jordan Sissel's [`fpm`](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm). It makes packaging an absolute joy.

Comment: I'm asking out of curiosity and ignorance here: Why do you say that the presence of compilers are a "significant security issue?" What's the security issue with having a compiler installed? Is it just a matter of you shouldn't be building your code on a production server in the first place and thus the compiler is superfluous, or is there actually a significant security issue with the presence of the compiler itself?

Comment: While it's a good idea to build your applications on a separate server, saying the presence of compilers on a production system is a significant security issue doesn't make sense. What about scripting languages and JIT-compiled systems (Perl, Python, Java, ...)?

Comment: The presence of of compilers on a production environment is **not** a "significant security risk". I, myself, have moved binaries to compromised boxes using `echo` and `base64`. In fact, you can even [do it with a series of `echo` statements and no other tool](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57310/a-tiny-version-of-wget-51-bytes).

Comment: Good points, all. I've edited my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 16):

`make` is a shell that has a different syntax than `bash`.

A compiler like `gcc` is a powerful `awk` configured with a set of substitutions that standard `awk` does not support. It is a non-POSIX-compliant `sort` or `cat` that injects rubbish in the output. It is an interactive text editor (think `vi`) which is configured to do some editing on startup, then exit before displaying the user interface.

There is nothing inherently insecure in them, they do not make your machine more insecure than one where you have bash + `cat` + shell redirection.

Comment: An answer so zen I don't know how to rate it.

Comment: @kasperd This answer is intended to be serious. I thought that bringing a programmer's point of view could be helpful. A function that translates an input into an output does not introduce a vulnerability just because its output is in a CPU-understandable format.

Comment: I agree with the point you are making. I think your answer is a great read to anybody who already agree with it. I am just worried that your answer may come across as a joke to somebody who disagree with it.

Comment: I like this answer much more than the accepted one :)

Answer (score 10):

On the contrary, the potential issue isn't with having `make` on the production server, the potential issue is with building the applications on the production server instead of deploying tested pre-built images. There may be valid reasons for this methodology, but it's one I would argue against strenuously were I asked to adopt it.

Answer (score 4):

You’re asking if `make` should be installed on a production server, but my real question would be: Who has access to that production server & what safeguards do you have in place to deal with an incursion? If `make` was not installed but someone gain `root` access, guess what? They can manually install `make` and anything they want.

The harsh reality about computer security is as much as you want to prevent unwanted access, being obsessed with blocking access is not as important as:

1. Who has access to the server?
2. What can you do to rollback from the aftermath of a break in?

This is all dependent on what kind of work you do. I work primarily in the web server world & my attitude is basically, anyone getting production server access from me needs to prove skills, knowledge & maturity. That’s it. Sometimes it takes a few days. Sometimes it takes months. But basically, your best line of security on production servers is controlling access on top of the sundry other things we do to harden servers.

Answer (score 1):

`make` itself is harmless. All it does is run applications in a set order, depending on dependencies you specify and what files already exist in the system. It can even be useful as part of the install process: you can use it to put prebuilt files where they need to go, or run unit tests, or other things.

However, you do need to consider what *exactly* you want to use it for. It is often used in conjunction with compilers and other tools for building applications, and *those* could be used to negate some of your lines of defense. But `make` can't do these things if the tools aren't available.